# "unresolved reference" in ternary if else one liner

Tags: python, python-3.9

I am trying to work out why the following line doesn't work:

```py
i = 0 if i // 3 == 0 else i += 1
```

I am getting an "unresolved reference 'i' " error despite the fact that i is defined before this line. Apologies if this is obvious but I am pretty new to ternaries and haven't been able to find a good reason why this doesn't work (although I suspect it may be something to do with the augmented assignment).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is that `i += 1` is a statement, not an expression.  A working line would be: `i = 0 if i // 3 == 0 else i+1`

Comment: i.e. this syntax works like: `(variable) = (expression1) if (condition) else (expression2)`.  Not like `(statement1) if (condition) else (statement2)`.

Comment: @slothrop thanks for the info. Your code works but i is no longer incremented. Do you know of a way to make the line work as originally intended?

Comment: If i starts at 0, then indeed it will never increment, because `i//3 == 0` !

Comment: try setting `i=5`, then running `i = 0 if i // 3 == 0 else i+1`.  After that, `i == 6` as presumably intended.

Comment: yep sorry face palm moment there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change this to `i = 0 if i // 3 == 0 else i + 1`. The reason for this is that it parses as `i = (0 if i // 3 == 0 else i + 1)`, not `(i = 0) if (i // 3 == 0) else (i + 1)` as you seem to assume.